# Natural language generation for Japanese

Tags: nlp, language, statistics, documentation-generator, japanese

I am looking for tools, libraries, software or services to generate natural Japanese text from raw data.

The best example of what I am trying to do is the commercial tool Wordsmith from Automated Insight. This tool takes in raw data like sport statistics and generates plain English reports.

I have found promising tools on an [NLG](http://www.nlg-wiki.org/systems/Table_of_NLG_systems) web site, but the ones I have tried so far (2) are either not supported or not available anymore.

Python libraries for NLP may work as well, but I would prefer to stand on some generation giant's shoulders.

Comment: If you use NLP you will be standing on the shoulders of a number of giants.

Comment: Thank you; I rephrased that part. It is really the NLG part of NLP that matters here. At this point I did not check yet how far and well NLG is supported in Python.

Comment: One simplistic approach from a few years ago: http://www.gilesthomas.com/2010/05/generating-political-news-using-nltk/